# Setting Retention Period on a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am  trying to set up retention policy on a data extension. However, I am not able to do so. Has someone tried this before?

Code after Comments:

```
   <script runat = "server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var name = "Test";
try{
    var de = {
        Name: name,
        CustomerKey: name,
        Description: "Test",
        Fields: [{
            FieldType: "Text",
            Name: "Field1",
            MaxLength: 254,
            IsPrimaryKey: true,
            IsNillable: false,
            IsRequired: true
    },
    {
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "Field2",
        MaxLength: 254
    }],
    DataRetentionPeriodLength: 7,
    DataRetentionPeriod: "Days",
    RowBasedRetention: 0,
    ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport: 1,
    DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod: 0
}
     var res = prox.createItem("DataExtension", de);
    }
  catch(e)
  {
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
 
  </script>
```

**Update**
If this runs on a cloudpage, When I display the `res` variable, I get data extension permission issue. However, checked with my admin and have all the necessary permissions.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you mean SSJS platform functions, yes?

Comment: Yes :) That's correct!

Comment: Platform functions cannot do this, do you mean the Core library instead? Or perhaps just SSJS in general (WSProxy, API, etc...)

Comment: I wanted to do it using the platform functions, since I have already a script that creates a DE using the platform functions. I tried using wsproxy , but doesn't work either!

Comment: Please post as much code as you can.

Comment: Platform functions are very similar to AMPScript and cannot create a DE without using API. As @Timothy stated, please post the code so we can better undersand and troubleshoot.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: is this on a cloudpage or a script activity?

Comment: Cloudpage! Did not try on script activity , can do that

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you share the error you are receiving

Comment: @Gortonington No error, but it doesn't create a DE

Comment: Write the `res` variable out to see status(`Write(Stringify(res))`). If you already have the DE created or there is a mismatch or incorrect syntax in the DE Object, this is where you would get those notifications.

Comment: @Gortonington: Updated my question above :)